# Delete Lines from Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have this shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting download"
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch3
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch2
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch1
echo "download finish"
```

i want to delete the line after execution.

Comment: What line do you want to remove?! The "starting download" line?

Comment: Or do you want to suppress the o/p of youtube-dl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "delete the **line** after execution.  But it seems reasonable that maybe you want to delete the file after it runs?

Just add:

```
rm $0
```

At the end of your file.  $0 expands to the name of the command that started the execution.

Comment: hi !! Guys !! I want to delete .. the website link after downloading

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to remove the first line "starting download" when the download is finished.

You can do that with:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "starting download"
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch3
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch2
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch1
echo -e "\rdownload finish  "
```

Comment: Add some extra spaces to the second `echo`, or it will appear as `download finishad`.